# Prevent text to break flexbox container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit image in with text link to flexbox container. The problem that it's break my container and it's become look like next on small screen:

[image]

```
 <el-container>
    <el-main>
      <div class="top">
        <div class="download-compiler">
            <div class="dmd-download">
                <el-image src="http://dlang.ru/imgs/dmd_logo_128.png"></el-image>
                <el-link style="color: black; font-size: 1.3em;">DMD</el-link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="code-snippets">
          <div class="code-snippets-header">
            Samples:
          </div>

          <div class="code-snippets-content"></div>          

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="middle">
        <div class="main-app-img">
        </div>
      </div>

    </el-main>
</el-container>
```

Here is minimal jsfiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/dhoc4zw5/

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. BUt you may solve it by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` on the flex container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but in your jsfiddle, just removing `height: 20%` from class `.top` make the image and text always stay in the pink zone.